# WiFi problem in ubuntu 14.04 Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 4965 AG or AGN [Kedron] Network Connection

Tags: wireless, intel

My WiFi connect is slow, block. I install a fresh Ubuntu copy.

This is my config: can someone help me?

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 04 May 2015 16:03 EEST +0300

Booted last: 04 May 2015 15:54 EEST +0300

Script from: 30 Apr 2015 17:23 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.13.0-51-generic #84-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 15 12:11:46 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8055 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller [11ab:4363] (rev 14)
    Subsystem: Fujitsu Limited. Device [10cf:139a]
    Kernel driver in use: sky2

0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 4965 AG or AGN [Kedron] Network Connection [8086:4229] (rev 61)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 4965 AG or AGN [8086:1101]
    Kernel driver in use: iwl4965

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 1199:6832 Sierra Wireless, Inc. MC8780 Device
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 08ff:2580 AuthenTec, Inc. AES2501 Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:09b2 Logitech, Inc. Fujitsu Webcam
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0c24:000f Taiyo Yuden Bluetooth Device (V2.0+EDR)
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

PRODID_1=""
PRODID_2=""
PRODID_3=""
PRODID_4=""
MANFID=0000,0000
FUNCID=255

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

iwl4965               106859  0 
iwlegacy               88016  1 iwl4965
mac80211              546067  2 iwl4965,iwlegacy
cfg80211              409394  3 iwl4965,iwlegacy,mac80211

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.16.100  Bcast:192.168.16.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::217:42ff:fe75:ffb4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:35142 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:24967 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:43038297 (43.0 MB)  TX bytes:2552408 (2.5 MB)
          Interrupt:16 

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.16.102  Bcast:192.168.16.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21d:e0ff:fe31:7c47/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:760 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:718 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:754054 (754.0 KB)  TX bytes:75922 (75.9 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"Rlink"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'Rlink' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=52 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-30 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:54   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.16.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.16.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.16.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search RalinkAP

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0  [Rlink 1] -----------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            iwl4965
  State:             connected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           52 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    TP-LINK_C08FDA:  Infra, <MAC 'TP-LINK_C08FDA' [AC2]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 72 WPA WPA2
    TP-LINK_A4C78A:  Infra, <MAC 'TP-LINK_A4C78A' [AC3]>, Freq 2427 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 25 WPA2
    Clicknet-9B5C:   Infra, <MAC 'Clicknet-9B5C' [AC4]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 22 WPA2
    TP-LINK_408CA2:  Infra, <MAC 'TP-LINK_408CA2' [AC5]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 19 WPA WPA2
    *Rlink:          Infra, <MAC 'Rlink' [AC1]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 93 WPA WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.16.102
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.16.1

    DNS:             192.168.16.1

- Device: eth0  [Conexiune cu fir 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            sky2
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.16.100
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.16.1

    DNS:             192.168.16.1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Rlink 2]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Rlink 2 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Rlink | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Rlink]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Rlink | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Rlink | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Rlink 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Rlink 1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Rlink | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Bucharest (based on set time zone)

country TW:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 27)
    (5270 - 5330 @ 40), (3, 17), DFS
    (5735 - 5815 @ 40), (3, 30)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

eth0      no frequency information.

wlan0     14 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Current Frequency=2.412 GHz (Channel 1)

##### iwlist scan #######################

Channel occupancy:

      2   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'Rlink' [AC1]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-28 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Rlink"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000001bd449b5c
                    Extra: Last beacon: 76ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'TP-LINK_C08FDA' [AC2]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=40/70  Signal level=-70 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"TP-LINK_C08FDA"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000e0fa910d5b
                    Extra: Last beacon: 76ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC 'TP-LINK_A4C78A' [AC3]>
                    Channel:4
                    Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
                    Quality=22/70  Signal level=-88 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"TP-LINK_A4C78A"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000087e78088db
                    Extra: Last beacon: 76ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 04 - Address: <MAC 'Clicknet-9B5C' [AC4]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=21/70  Signal level=-89 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Clicknet-9B5C"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000e0f90e677d
                    Extra: Last beacon: 76ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 05 - Address: <MAC 'TP-LINK_408CA2' [AC5]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=23/70  Signal level=-87 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"TP-LINK_408CA2"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000dd429a36f2
                    Extra: Last beacon: 76ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

0000008000000000000000000000
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[iwl4965]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlegacy/iwl4965.ko
firmware:       iwlwifi-4965-2.ucode
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003-2011 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi 4965 driver for Linux
srcversion:     0C07ED8F3D47BC4C25E124D
depends:        iwlegacy,cfg80211,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-51-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        1F:88:72:3D:CE:40:86:A1:23:03:DA:DD:54:A7:AE:35:E9:E4:4D:58
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           queues_num:number of hw queues. (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality (int)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (int)

[iwlegacy]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlegacy/iwlegacy.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003-2011 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    iwl-legacy: common functions for 3945 and 4965
srcversion:     A847A747E4E6066D74E1D6A
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-51-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        1F:88:72:3D:CE:40:86:A1:23:03:DA:DD:54:A7:AE:35:E9:E4:4D:58
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking (int)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bluetooth co-exist (bool)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     29A87AE7782ED3657631C32
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-51-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        1F:88:72:3D:CE:40:86:A1:23:03:DA:DD:54:A7:AE:35:E9:E4:4D:58
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     176113E009F723E69BE9BAB
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-51-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        1F:88:72:3D:CE:40:86:A1:23:03:DA:DD:54:A7:AE:35:E9:E4:4D:58
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwl4965]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size_8K: 1
fw_restart: 1
queues_num: 0
swcrypto: 0

[iwlegacy]
bt_coex_active: Y
led_mode: 0

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x11ab:0x4363 (sky2)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x8086:0x4229 (iwl4965)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[   18.349457] iwl4965: Intel(R) Wireless WiFi 4965 driver for Linux, in-tree:
[   18.349458] iwl4965: Copyright(c) 2003-2011 Intel Corporation
[   18.349519] iwl4965 0000:0c:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[   18.349725] iwl4965 0000:0c:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link 4965AGN, REV=0x4
[   18.389866] iwl4965 0000:0c:00.0: device EEPROM VER=0x36, CALIB=0x5
[   18.392593] iwl4965 0000:0c:00.0: Tunable channels: 13 802.11bg, 19 802.11a channels
[   18.392697] iwl4965 0000:0c:00.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
[   18.765491] iwl4965 0000:0c:00.0: loaded firmware version 228.61.2.24
[   18.778655] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-4965-rs'
[   20.981256] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[   23.276551] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'Rlink' [AC1]>
[   23.294555] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'Rlink' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   23.296435] wlan0: authenticated
[   23.300030] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'Rlink' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   23.303847] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Rlink' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[   23.332798] wlan0: associated
[   23.332830] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[  183.831597] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC 'Rlink' [AC1]> by local choice (reason=3)
[  472.501407] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'Rlink' [AC1]>
[  472.501551] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'Rlink' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[  472.503446] wlan0: authenticated
[  472.508053] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'Rlink' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[  472.511925] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Rlink' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[  472.537700] wlan0: associated

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: This must be mot related to Ubuntu. I used this adapter on all versions of Ubuntu and all kernels from 3.0.0 to 3.19. It works well.